# Unity/.NET reflection and AR foundation error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, augmented-reality, arcore

I've been working on a Unity project with ARCore for an Android mobile application, and everything was fine for several Git commits. I even reverted to a past commit to troubleshoot an issue, but no luck. I haven't manually changed anything related to ARCore, so I suspect it might be a high-level editor or Unity application error.

Here's the full traceback for the error:

```
ArgumentException: method arguments are incompatible

System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, System.Boolean throwOnBindFailure, System.Boolean allowClosed) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)

System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Object firstArgument, System.Reflection.MethodInfo method) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)

UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall..ctor (System.Object target, System.Reflection.MethodInfo theFunction) (at <49f4e7e791cc4fffacd88f729e2b1e4c>:0)

UnityEngine.Events.PersistentCall.GetRuntimeCall (UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase theEvent) (at <49f4e7e791cc4fffacd88f729e2b1e4c>:0)

UnityEngine.Events.PersistentCallGroup.Initialize (UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList invokableList, UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase unityEventBase) (at <49f4e7e791cc4fffacd88f729e2b1e4c>:0)

UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.RebuildPersistentCallsIfNeeded () (at <49f4e7e791cc4fffacd88f729e2b1e4c>:0)

UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.PrepareInvoke () (at <49f4e7e791cc4fffacd88f729e2b1e4c>:0)

UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at <49f4e7e791cc4fffacd88f729e2b1e4c>:0)

UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at E:/Programs/2020.1.2f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:68)

UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at E:/Programs/2020.1.2f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:110)

UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at E:/Programs/2020.1.2f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)

UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction\1[T1] functor) (at E:/Programs/2020.1.2f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)`

UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at E:/Programs/2020.1.2f1/Editor/Data/Resources/PackageManager/BuiltInPackages/com.unity.ugui/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:376)
```

Answer (score 0):

check Package Manager and uninstall and reinstall Arfondation and Arcore and their dependencies.

Another way is making a new fresh project and installing all you need in the package manager. then import old broken project assets and codes into the new project

Comment: This didn't work for my issue. In fact it made it worst/broke the project with more errors (that's okay I have my project backed up via github) -- I'm still open to new solutions.